# Migrate physical server to virtual on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, hard-drive, mdadm

I have a physical linux server that I'm considering moving to a virtual linux server running on the standalone Hyper-V R2 hypervisor.  Theres alot of unused cycles on that box that could be shared with other machines.  Normally this would be a pretty easy choice, but this particular server is hosting an mdadm raid5 array on it.  Once I get a similar linux virtual server running, is there a way to add the discs that make up the array to the virtual machine and have it use them directly?

In other words, I dont want to have to convert them all to virtual discs and then rebuild the array; I want to just use the existing discs and partitions in a kind of 'pass through' mode.  The array is working just fine, I dont want to go through all the I/O of moving it off these discs to new, virtual, ones.  Hyper-V supports a mode called 'passthrough', would that do the trick?

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Are you sure that ESXi will run on your existing server?   Are you sure the hard drive controller is supported under ESXi?

Comment: ESXi?  He's talking about Hyper-V from Microsoft, not ESXi from VMware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  In the Hyper-V management OS, take those disks offline.  This can be done either with the Disk Management MMC snapin or through the command line with diskpart.exe.  Then, when configuring the VM, add a Virtual SCSI controller and attach hard disks to it.  The disks that you offlined will show up as candidates for assignment.

Comment: I've found that it's also important to have the administrator account from the Hyper-V server registered via cmdkey (or similar) on the administration client machine.  Otherwise, the client cant connect to the VDS service and enumerate the disks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to setup a [raw device mapping](http://vmzare.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/vmware-raw-device-mappingrdm/).  It depends a lot on what type of hardware you have.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do the raw device mapping. I've not used Hyper-V, but on VMware Workstation I had a Linux install I ran physically as well as from within Workstation on Windows. I identified my array with UUIDs to allow device names to change without issue (e.g. /dev/sda becoming /dev/hda or something similar), this worked without problems. As long as Hyper-V allows you to directly access drives you could likely virtualize the whole machine with a minimum of downtime and fuss. Linux won't complain too much about hardware changes as long as you have proper support for the Hyper-V virtual hardware, which is generally built off generic drivers.